# WebAPI Client -- handle my own exception rather then AggregateException

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have written a very simple WebApiClient extending HttpClient. The code is following. The main reason to do that was to throw MyOwnWebApiException when httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode is false.

```
 public class WebApiClient : HttpClient
{

    public WebApiClient(string apiBaseUrl)
    {
        this.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUrl);
        this.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    }

    public void AddAcceptHeaders(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue header)
    {
        this.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(header);
    }

    public async Task<string> DoPost(string endPoint, Object dataToPost)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await ((HttpClient)this).PostAsJsonAsync(endPoint, dataToPost);
        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string rawResponse = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return rawResponse;
        }
        else
        {
            string rawException = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            MyOwnWebApiErrorResponse exception =
             JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyOwnApiErrorResponse>(rawException, GetJsonSerializerSettings());

            throw new MyOwnWebApiException (exception.StatusCode,exception.Message,exception.DeveloperMessage,exception.HelpLink);
        }
    }


    #region "Private Methods"

    private static JsonSerializerSettings GetJsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        // Serializer Settings
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor,
            ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Auto
        };
        return settings;
    }

    #endregion
```

Following is the code of the class using WebApiClient.

```
    class TestWebApiClient
{
    private WebApiClient _client;
    public ComputationProcessesWebApiClient()
    {
        _client = new WebApiClient("http://test.api/");
        _client.AddAcceptHeaders(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    }

    public void GetData(string dataFor)
    {
        try
        {
            DataRequest request = new DataRequest();
            request.dataFor = dataFor;

            **// THIS LINE IS THROWING AGGREGATEEXCEPTION--- **I WANT MyOwnException ****
            string response = _client.DoPost("GetData", request).Result;   // Use the End Point here ....

        }
        catch (MyOwnWebApiException exception)
        {
            //Handle exception here
         }
    }

}
```

**Question**
In the TestWebApiClient class, i dont want to catch AggregateException, rather i want to keep it more elegent and catch MyOwnWebApiException, but the problem is the line ** _client.DoPost("GetData", request).Result** throws an AggregateException if something goes wrong from the WebApi. How to change the code so that from TestWebApiClient i only have to catch MyOwnException ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as a result of synchronously waiting for your task. If you stay async and await your task instead, you'll find that your actual Exception is the one that is caught.

Compare the following below:

```
void Main()
{
    TryCatch();
    TryCatchAsync();
}
void TryCatch()
{
    try
    {
        ThrowAnError().Wait();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //AggregateException
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
async Task TryCatchAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await ThrowAnError();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //MyException
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
async Task ThrowAnError()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    throw new MyException();
}
public class MyException:Exception{};
```

Top hint for async/await? It's async/await all the way down. The moment you `.Wait()` or `.Result` on a `Task`, things start to get messy.

Comment: Thanks alot. That means if i have to call .Wait( ) or .Result( ) i will have to catch AggregateException otherwise, if i just use await keywork with my call to the DoPost then i should be able to catch MyOwnWebApiException directly. I tried that and it worked.